# How do I insert a blob into mysql using typescript / mysql package

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, blob

I am rather surprised I am not finding more answers about this.
I am trying to use javascript/typescript and the mysql package to insert a blob using the following code:

```
import mysql, {Connection} from 'mysql';
import {readFileSync} from "fs";

const NAME = 'GMDev';
const HOST = 'localhost';
const PORT = 3306;
const USER = 'gm_dev';
const PASSWD = 'secret';

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: HOST,
    user: USER,
    password: PASSWD,
    database: NAME
});

function query(db: Connection, sql: string, data?: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, data, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    })
}

let sql = '';
const imgData = readFileSync('./test.png');
console.log(`buffer length: ${imgData.length}`);
sql = "INSERT INTO image (type,image) VALUES('product',BINARY (?))";
const data = {image: imgData};
let result = query(db, sql, data).then((result) => {
    console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
}).then(() => {
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM image';
    return query(db, sql);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error ${err}`);
});
```

The Database table is as follows:

```
create table image
(
    id    int auto_increment primary key,
    type  enum ('product', 'card', 'other') null,
    image blob not null
);
```

The output of my little test program looks like this:

```
buffer length: 336922
result: {"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":1,"insertId":5,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
result: [{"id":5,"type":"product","image":{"type":"Buffer","data":[48]}}]
```

Meaning:
My buffer is 336922 bytes long and a row was inserted, but the blob only contains one byte.

Any ideas ?

Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
For starters I have no idea where I got this from:

```
const data = {image: imgData};
```

When I use an array of objects instead it works..
Also the BLOB is not actually capable of taking the size of data I am trying to insert, at least on MariaDB (which I am using) I need to use MEDIUMBLOB.